# Flash ROM has lower max voltage than read device?

Tags: flash, bios, rom

I'm planning to read a MX25U1635E chip using the CH341a reader.

The specs for that chip say it has a max voltage of 1.6-2.0 volts. The reader has an output of 3.3-5.0 volts.

Most tutorials for the reader instruct you to just clamp it on the chip and start reading.

Can I do that in my case, or do I have tweak the CH341a voltage down somehow before reading the chip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MX25U1635E is designed for 1.8 volt logic, whereas your programmer is designed for 3.3 or 5.0 volt logic. You're going to need a 1.8 volt adapter for the programmer or you will damage the MX25U1635E.

If you google CH341A 1.8 volt adapter, you can find them for relatively cheap.

Comment: Just did some online shopping. It looks like I'll be waiting a while if I order one. Is there something better than the CH341a for flashing/reading chips. Also something for JTAG, UART, etc?

Comment: If the CH341a does everything you need, may be worth it to just buy another one with the kit that includes the 1.8 volt adapter.

Comment: Better is a very subjective term, but I personally use a GQ 4x4 for chips, and a bus pirate for everything else.